# Can we write every $\frac{1}{n}\in\mathbb Z$ as $\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha_j}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that for a polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$, we can write $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ in partial fraction decomposition, i.e. we can write
$\frac{1}{p(x)}$ as combinaison of $\frac{1}{(aX+b)^i}$ or $\frac{aX+b}{(cX^2+dX+e)^k}$ where $cX^2+dX+e$ irreducible. Is it the same for number in $\mathbb Z$ ? i.e. if $n\in\mathbb Z$, can we write $\frac{1}{n}$ as sum of $\frac{1}{p^{\alpha _i}}$ ?

Comment: I think you meant "$p(x)\in \mathbb R[x]$" (otherwise you should allow irreducible polynomials of higher degree). See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743055/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the fact that for a collection of integers we can express their greatest common divisor as a linear combination (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$) of these integers. Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}$. Then the greatest common divisor of the numbers $\frac{n}{p_1^{a_1}},\ldots, \frac{n}{p_k^{a_k}}$ is 1 and hence
there exist $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
1 = \sum x_i \frac{n}{p_i^{a_i}}.
$$
Dividing by $n$ you get the result you look for.

Comment: And thus, that's why it also work on $\mathbb Z[X]$ ? (or maxbe I should say $Frac(\mathbb Z[x])$ ?

Comment: @user386627: It works over PIDs like $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ but $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID (only a unique factorisation domain). In particular $\frac{1}{2X}$ cannot be written as a sum of inverses of powers of irreducible elements.